# Uniquely Identify an Android Handset

Tags: android

Is there a unique ID that is given to Android handests that is available through the SDK?

I want to provide a web-service with actions that can only be performed once per resource per user.  Maybe there is a different way to go about this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the phone Imei as described here: http://www.androidsoftwaredeveloper.com/2009/04/02/how-to-get-the-phone-imei/

```
String imei = TelephonyManager.getDefault().getDeviceId();
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(imei)) {
   return "";
}
```

You need the read phone state permission to access this data. So you have to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

to your manifest file.

Comment: Be aware that this permission will be shown to the user during installation and that privacy concerned users may down rate your app for asking for access for the imei. The imei is a type that normally should not be accessed and transmitted to a server lightly. Maybe use a hash of the imei or something instead of saving it of somewhere else. Look at this blog post about privacy and data etc.: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/08/best-practices-for-handling-android.html

Comment: I am just finding out that this does not always work.  It is tied to the TelephonyManager.  As noted in [this Android issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=721&can=1&q=getDeviceId&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars), "some android devices do not have a cellular radio and your application will probably fail there."

Answer (score 2):

Use the IMEI for identifying handsets. This is one of the most reliable source.

```
TelephonyManager.getDefault().getDeviceId();
```

Comment: Will this return the MEID on CDMA?